# WINDBG, how to view the contents of an array?

Tags: arrays, windbg, managed-extensions

I'm using WINDBG to analyze a dump file for a program that exhibits a bit too high memory usage.

One of the objects involved is holding an object array, referencing a lot of objects I'd like to look at, to try to find out why they were allocated.

Here's what I've tried:

First, my collection of ServiceContainer objects:

```
0:000> !do 05633014 
Name: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[LVK.IoC.ServiceContainer, LVK.Core]]
MethodTable: 08b3c7fc
EEClass: 6f70ca78
Size: 24(0x18) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
6f924324  40009d8        4      System.Object[]  0 instance 1da226ec _items
6f952da0  40009d9        c         System.Int32  1 instance     5356 _size
6f952da0  40009da       10         System.Int32  1 instance     5538 _version
6f950770  40009db        8        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 _syncRoot
6f924324  40009dc        0      System.Object[]  0   shared   static _emptyArray
    >> Domain:Value dynamic statics NYI
 002b2a28:NotInit  <<
```

The `_items` array there is the one I want to look at, so I issued this command:

```
0:000> !do 1da226ec
```

which produced:

```
Name: System.Object[]
MethodTable: 6f924324
EEClass: 6f70da64
Size: 32784(0x8010) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 8192, Type CLASS
Element Type: LVK.IoC.ServiceContainer
Fields:
None
```

Looking at the web, I've found [indications](http://blogs.msdn.com/alikl/archive/2009/03/09/windbg-walkthrough-dump-values-of-dataset-or-datatable.aspx) that there was a `-v` option I could use on something to produce the array values, but this doesn't seem to work.

How do I look at the elements of this array?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're looking for

```
!da 1da226ec
```

To dump the array objects.

Comment: With details: !da -details 1da226ec