# C# ensuring shuffled memory allocation for elements in List<T>

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, allocation

Most of the answers here about memory allocation in managed environment say "You don't need to bother with such things, let the platform handle it". Truth is in some cases you DO need to worry about such things.
I have a list of objects, which, in case of memory dump, I do not want to be allocated sequentially on a straight row of consecutive addresses. I want them scattered.
Is there any way (a trick or hack will do) to ensure objects are not allocated sequentially, and can not be recognized as a sequence in a memory dump?
Thank you!

**EDIT:** The reason for this is that I'm trying to circumvent the way MySQL for .NET requires me to pass sensitive data as a connection string. My idea was to keep everything in a scattered char list, then assemble it before connection.Open(), and dispose of it immediately after. Is there a better way? I'd rather not keep database credentials in memory like that.

**CONCLUSION:** It seems impossible to protect sensitive data from memory dump by scattering it. In my specific case, I'll be using SecureString where I can, and will be looking for other ways to not expose unencrypted passwords to MySQL.

**UPDATE:** After some digging around, this is what I ended up doing: All my SQL is executed by local service, with account restricted to stored procedures and localhost. In order to request the SP call, clients have to authenticate via SHA512 hashed password + salt. On the client, the password is read char by char from the textbox, and appended onto a Secure String, then text is replaced with system pass char. Then the Secure String is hashed and the original data is zeroed out, like this:

```
public static string GetSHA512(SecureString secureInput)
    {
        if (secureInput == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("securePassword");

        IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
        byte[] dataUnmanaged = new byte[secureInput.Length];
        try
        {
            unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi(secureInput);
            Marshal.Copy(unmanagedString, dataUnmanaged, 0, dataUnmanaged.Length);

            using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
            {
                byte[] hash = shaM.ComputeHash(dataUnmanaged);
                int i = 0;
                while (i < dataUnmanaged.Length)
                {
                    dataUnmanaged[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                }
                StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
                foreach (byte b in hash)
                    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
                return hex.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < dataUnmanaged.Length)
            {
                dataUnmanaged[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
            Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocAnsi(unmanagedString);
        }
    }
```

The resulting hash is further hashed with a random salt and sent to the service for confirmation along with the salt. Service re-hashes its hashed pass with the salt and compares. Once approved, further authentication happens via constantly changing unique session IDs that both the client and the server track. Any hijacking and the session is immediately invalidated. That way the password is used only once, transferred only double-hashed, and stored in a SecureString for as short a time as possible.
This is the best I could come up with. I'll update further if something new pops up, thanks to everybody.

Comment: No. The garbage collector will rearrange them anyway. Even if they are not "sorted" in memory, they'll be easy to find. Let me mention  WinDbg + SOS + `!dumpheap`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not at all proficient in memory dumps, so I don't know what SOS is, but on your estimate, how easy is it to hunt down objects from a collection in their original order from a memory dump? Also, are you saying GC will sort objects in the memory by order in the collection?

Comment: @Daniel "how easy is it to hunt down objects from a collection in their original order from a memory dump?". It's a rather simple task.

Comment: It would certainly take some time to find the list in question, because there are typically many lists in a dump (if not a HelloWorld). Once that's done, it's simple: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2198805/480982

Comment: Use `SecureString` and encryption instead.

Comment: Re your conclusion.  If your connection string uses https at least you are guaranteed the database you are talking to.  http://razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html

Comment: You didn't mention that using Integrated Security is not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Memory layout

There's no benefit in moving .NET objects to random positions in memory, due to the internal structure of lists in .NET. In fact, your objects may already be at "random" addresses and the garbage collector may change that at any time (based on memory needs, not due to sorting of lists).

The only exception to that are arrays, which are allocated as one block. And exactly those arrays will be the problem, because ...

Internally, a list is an array of "pointers" to objects, so independent of where the objects are located, once someone has access to that array, he'll be able to access all objects in order.

The following graph hopefully illustrates this:

[image]

Using the [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) debugger and a .NET extension called [sos](/questions/tagged/sos), the following commands will make it very easy to find an array and print the objects in it:

```
!dumpheap -type List
!dumparray
!dumpobj
```

In your case, using a SecureString (as mentioned by others already) will ensure that the password is encrypted in memory and nobody can easily (it's still possible) reveal it.

### Overwriting memory

Regarding the followup question from the comments

> Can you please tell me if setting myByteArray[n] = 0; actually zeroes out the previous value, or allocates new memory for the 0 and stores a reference to it, while the original value at n still resides somewhere waiting for the GC? It is related to my question.

Let's write the following program:

```
using System;

namespace OverwriteValuesInMemory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Ensure we have it on the heap
            var program = new Program();
            program.FillAndRefill();
            Console.WriteLine("Create a dump now");
            Console.ReadLine();
            // Access to prevent it from being optimized away
            program.nonboxed[0]=0;
        }

        const int M16 = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
        byte[] nonboxed = new byte[M16];
        object[] boxed = new object[M16];

        void FillAndRefill()
        { 
            Fill(nonboxed, 42);
            Fill(boxed, 23);
            Fill(nonboxed, 0x42);
            Fill(boxed, 0x23);
        }

        private void Fill(object[] array, int value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
                array[i] = value;
        }

        private void Fill(byte[] array, byte value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
                array[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Ans then let's debug it with WinDbg + SOS. The output of some commands may be shortened, since it does not really matter for the outcome, but I wanted to include the commands to make it self-contained:

```
0:005> .symfix
0:005> .reload
0:005> .loadby sos clr
0:005> ~0s
```

We can find the reference to `Program` on the stack

```
0:000> !dso
[...]
0042EE4C 02553128 OverwriteValuesInMemory.Program
[...]
```

Or alternatively, search it among all objects in the heap

```
0:000> !dumpheap -type Program
 Address       MT     Size
02553128 001c4d44       16
```

Looking at the details of the object

```
0:000> !do 02553128
Name:        OverwriteValuesInMemory.Program
MethodTable: 001c4d44
EEClass:     001c1394
Size:        16(0x10) bytes
File:        E:\Projekte\SVN\HelloWorlds\OverwriteValuesInMemory\OverwriteValuesInMemory\bin\Release\OverwriteValuesInMemory.exe
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
70cd35fc  4000002        4        System.Byte[]  0 instance 04821010 nonboxed
70cced0c  4000003        8      System.Object[]  0 instance 06981010 boxed
```

we find the 2 members for boxed and nonboxed values, which we can inspect in raw memory. The nonboxed array has the values directly inside:

```
0:000> db 04821010 L20
04821010  fc 35 cd 70 00 00 00 01-42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42  .5.p....BBBBBBBB
04821020  42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42-42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42  BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

While that isn't the case for the boxed one:

```
0:000> db 06981010 L20
06981010  0c ed cc 70 00 00 00 01-d8 58 bd 1a e4 58 bd 1a  ...p.....X...X..
06981020  f0 58 bd 1a fc 58 bd 1a-08 59 bd 1a 14 59 bd 1a  .X...X...Y...Y..
```

Looking at the boxed one in sizes of a pointer, we see values at a distance of 0x0C (12), which is an indicator that there's some metadata overhead for the object.

```
0:000> dp 06981010 L10
06981010  70cced0c 01000000 1abd58d8 1abd58e4
06981020  1abd58f0 1abd58fc 1abd5908 1abd5914
06981030  1abd5920 1abd592c 1abd5938 1abd5944
06981040  1abd5950 1abd595c 1abd5968 1abd5974
```

Looking at the first of them gives us the expected value of 35 (0x23):

```
0:000> !do 1abd58d8
Name:        System.Int32
MethodTable: 70cd07a0
EEClass:     7090fd30
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
70cd07a0  400055f        4         System.Int32  1 instance       35 m_value
```

So the `Program` references only the last values set. That's expected. But what about the memory? Are the old values lurking around waiting for garbage collection? WinDbg IMHO isn't a good program for statistics, so I used HxD, which gives the following statistics:

[image]

Conclusion: nonboxed values were overwritten, while the boxed ones are not.

Comment: Hello, sorry, me again. Can you please tell me if setting myByteArray[n] = 0; actually zeroes out the previous value, or allocates new memory for the 0 and stores a reference to it, while the original value at n still resides somewhere waiting for the GC? It is related to my question :)

Comment: @Daniel: updated my answer to include the question from the comment

Comment: Thank you very much, what a wealth of info! I'll update my question with what I ended up doing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve by this?

If it is security, then you could encrypt your data/properties, or maybe the use of [SecureStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) is enough. GC is all about optimizing memory, not fragment it (which is effectively what you are asking for).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please check out my edit for context.

Comment: Are you just trying to protect the connection string? Store it securely in memory using SecureString as mentioned. Click through and look at the docs.